# dynamic module loading doesnot work in MSI package generated by cx_freeze

Tags: cx-freeze, python-3.9, python-click

I have a click based python application which dynamically loads relevant module like this.

```
 python cli.py --foo # imports only foo module
 python cli.py --bar  # imports only bar module
```

lib directory looks like:

```
lib
  ├───src
        ├───loader.py
  ├───modules 
        ├───foo
        ├───bar
```

in my code src/loader.py, this is how I am finding lib directory and then import correct module based on command line option

```
if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
     # The application is frozen
     datadir = path.dirname(sys.executable)
     libdir = path.dirname(datadir)

modules_dir = path.join(libdir , 'modules')
```

and based on CLI input, I import correct mod_path i.e foo.xxx or bar.xxx in src/loader.py

```
 __import__(modules_dir + mod_path)
```

While running "python setup.py build", build directory looks like this. **The generated exe works as expected.**

```
    Directory: C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\build


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/30/2022   1:01 PM                bdist.win-amd64
d-----         7/30/2022   4:03 PM                exe.win-amd64-3.9
d-----         7/30/2022   4:04 PM                lib
```

but when I generate MSI package and install it,and run `python cli.py --foo` it doesn't import foo module.

How can I debug what is wrong?

Update: The relative directory structure changes after I install msi. So I check 'AppData' in datadir path and then locate loader.py and finally modules directory. This approach works but is there an elegant way to do it?

```
# exe datadir : C:\Users\username\my_cli\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9
# exe loader.py C:\Users\username\my_cli\build\lib\src\loader.py
# msi datadir : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\my_cli
# msi loader.py is at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\my_cli\Lib\site-packages\src\loader.py
```